# Why is my equation giving Error must have an integral expression or unscoped enun type?

Tags: c++, function, syntax-error

so hey guys, I thought to make a simple program to learn about functions and I ran across this error I never had before could someone help me?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

float SphereVolume(float r);

int main() {

    /*

    Calculating a sphere.

    */
    float radius;
    cout << "Sphere Calc....\n";
    cout << "\tPlease Enter Radius of Sphere: ";
    cin << radius;

    SphereVolume(radius);

    return 0;
}


float SphereVolume(float r) {

    double const PI = 3.14159;
    float volume;

    volume = 4/3 * PI * r ^ 3; // error starts here.

    return volume;
}
```

I cant seem to understand why this is happening, the error, start when I try to declare the volume equation and it says the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got two errors and the first one gives you probably a wall of error codes:

```
cin << radius;
```

proper construction is:

```
cin >> radius;
```

Second error is the one you're actually asking of:

```
volume = 4 / 3 * PI * r ^ 3;
```

^ - is a xor operator that don't work on float types.
The resulting type from 4/3*PI*r is double. You cannot do xor (^) on it.

I think you actually tried to get the result to the power of three. In C++ there is no simple operator that can do it. You can use pow(..) function like this:

```
volume = pow(4 / 3 * PI * r, 3);
```

Remeber to add `#include <cmath>` to be able to use the function.

Comment: Thank you very much I used the pow() function I should search the cmath library.

Answer (score 3):

```
volume = 4/3 * PI * r ^ 3; // error starts here.

4 / 3 is integer division -> 1  

r ^ 3  is r xor-ed with the integer 3.
```

You can't xor a float.  If you want to cube a float, the simplest solution is to multiply it three times.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it, wow I had no clue, Why do you have restrictions like that when it comes to dealing with floats?

Comment: @VictorMartins The way xor works is that it manipulates bits. The bit representation is very rarely useful for floats or doubles, or any type besides the integer types.